# Compare two NSDate by .Day in swift is giving wrong results

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

Im trying to compare two NSDate by .Day doing this (both on gmt timezone):

```
 var order = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().compareDate(event.startDate!, toDate: cell.date!,
                    toUnitGranularity: .Day)
                    if (order == .OrderedSame) {
                            print(String(event.startDate!) + " == " + String(cell.date!))
                        cell.events.append(event)
                        break
                    }
```

When using 2016-03-08 21:43:53 +0000 and 2016-03-09 00:00:00 +0000 it says they are orderedSame, but they arent, the days are different. This function outputs:

```
 2016-03-08 21:43:53 +0000 == 2016-03-09 00:00:00 +0000
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: The result is likely correct with respect to your calendar's timezone. So print out your calendar's timezone or allocate a calendar and set the timezone where you want the result to be "correct".

Comment: You think they are on different days. But NSDate prints UTC, and they may be on different dates in UTC, but in your timezone, they are on the same date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those two logged dates are being logged in the UTC timezone. But if your current timezone is west of that, then both dates are on March 8, 2016 in your timezone and the comparison is done in your timezone. Or, if you live east of that by at least 2.5 hours, then both dates are March 9, 2016.

Example. If you live in the eastern USA (GMT-4 currently but GMT-5 on March 8), then those two dates are actually `2016-03-08 16:43:53 -0500` and `2016-03-08 19:00:00 -0500`.

Example. If you live in eastern Europe or Asia (say GMT+5), then those two dates would be `2016-03-09 02:43:53 +0500` and `2016-03-09 05:00:00 +0500`.

As you can see, those are on the same day so the comparison is correct.